# Rails cancan gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Hi i need help with new ( for me ) gem 'cancan'

i have a next problem: 
in my app i have 'Post' model and 'Photo' model ( routes: )

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :photos
  end
```

and in ability.rb i write:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new

    if user.roles.first.nil?
        can :read, Post
    #not logged
    elsif user.roles.first.name == "user"
        #loged in as user
        can :read, Post
        can :create, Post
        can :update, Post, :user_id => user.id
        can :destroy, Post , :user_id => user.id 

    elsif user.roles.first.name == "admin"
        # login as admin
        can :manage, Post
    end

  end
end
```

and i dont know how put thats logic: 
if post created by another user, current user does not have access to page

```
localhost:3000/post/97/photos
```

and he(current user) can't create there anything or destroy, in other words he can only read `localhost:3000/post/97/`

But if current user is autor - he have access to `localhost:3000/post/97/photos`, `localhost:3000/post/97/photos/new` and `localhost:3000/post/97/photo/244/show` ...

in ability something like that: 
can :destroy, Photo , @photo.post.user_id => user.id 
// but how to define @photo ?? or if you know an easier way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block like:

```
can :manage , Post  do | post |
  post.user_id == user.id
end
```

which means that only if the current user created the Post it is able to manage it.

Comment: no, if you lock in my ability - you saw that if user not a creator - he can read post =>  if I write "can :manage , Post  do | post |...." and after that i write "can :read, Post" - user have access to post/64/photo/new action even if he is not the author